# Basic Software Design Question Using Roles & Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, roles

I am in the process of looking at an API and I see the following two calls:

```
API.Users.Roles.getAllRoles();

API.Admin.Roles.getAllRoles();
```

What I would like to know is how each of these call is used within
the context of a Web program. Since both Admin and Users are properties,
what exactly is the get; set; doing? How does the call know which Admin
(or user) is making the call?

My hunch is that this has something to do with how the API class is 
instantiated (and session?) but I'd appreciate a walk-through on what is 
going on here so I fully understand it.

The (abbreviated) class structure looks like the following:

```
public class API() 
{
 public Admin Admin { get; private set; }
 public Users Users { get; private set; }
}

public class Users
{
 public Roles Roles { get; private set; }
    ...
}

 public class Roles
 {

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    { 
      ...
    }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It will check the current user name from the current principal (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) which uses forms/windows account depending on setup, or if not in the web environment, it will use the current windows user logged into the system.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that they have a custom role provider and are therefore overriding the [GetAllRoles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getallroles.aspx) method so that the roles can be obtained from the datasource. Without seeing further details, I can only assume, but when a user registers, they're probably assigned a particular role. They can then use the `Roles.IsUserInRole` method to detect what role the user is assigned to. There's more on custom role providers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) which will explain why methods are being overwritten.